# Unknown or uninitialised column when using Lag in calculation

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to refer to the previous row in the same column inside a calculation for said column. However this always leads to an 'Unknown or uninitialised column' warning message and a lot of NA's.

```
MovementData <- c(-1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 4) 
Database <- data.frame(MovementData) 

Database$Score <- ifelse(Database$MovementData <= 0 , 0,
                                    ifelse(lag(Database$Score,1) == 0,1,2))
```

Desired Output:

```
Database$Score <- c(0,0,0,1,2,2)
```

My intentions for the calculation is the following:
If the MovementData is negative, the score is 0. If the MovementData is positive AND the previous score was 0, the score is 1. If the MovementData is positive and the previous score was not 0, the score is 2.

This gives me the previously mentioned error. 
I'm looking for a way to use lag (or another function) which can refer to previous rows in the Database$Score column inside the calculation of the column itself.
How can i refer to previous rows in the same column when calculating said column?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I haven't run your code, but it's clearly incomplete (assignment operator missing?). Also, please format code as code.

Comment: Also, please complete the code, meaning actually creating a data frame. Please try to avoid object names such as 'df', because this is a base R function and you don't want to mess up with our environments.

Comment: And, last but not least, please provide desired output.

Comment: Hi @Tjebo, thanks for your comments. I am new to SO. I have made edits which i hope correct issues and explain my problem better.

Comment: Great. Now, a desired output would definitely help to understand what you are intending to do .

Comment: @Tjebo I tried to do so in my final 2 lines, what more information can i add to help explain? Or maybe i have misunderstood what you mean by desired output

Comment: I have edited your question slightly - you can format as code with 4spaces indent or just selecting everything and pressing 'ctrl + K' (or CMD+K for Mac). Desired output: How you want your column Database$Score to look like in the end

Comment: @Tjebo Thanks so much for the guidance. I have added a Desired output for the Scores column. Does this also need to be formatted as code?

Comment: ok. Ideally, again, format code as code , e.g. include assignment operator and add c() or so. I can't edit this because these are too few changes

Comment: @Tjebo I have made the changes. Is this all correct now?

Comment: Great. It looks much better. What you are realising now (hopefully) that your question might actually be about a very specific problem and not really a very general problem - and this is usually the best way to get help here, to ask very specific questions about a very specific problem.. In order for us to help you, the question is still a bit unclear. What do you exactly intend to create in the new column? What is your if-else statement exactly doing? This would be the kind of question we can help to solve - and this might also help you to understand how referencing works

Comment: @Tjebo Yes, this is one of my first posts so i am now learning how it works. Please see my last edit to explain my intentions.

Comment: Great. will have a look tomorrow - need to go to bed now :D or maybe someone else will find time to have a look.

Comment: @Tjebo Thanks! Look forward to hearing your suggesions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we need a recursive evaluation

```
Database$Score[1] <- 0

for(i in 2:nrow(Database)) {
      Database$Score[i] <- if(Database$MovementData[i] <= 0) {
                           0 } else if(Database$MovementData[i] > 0 &
                                    Database$Score[i-1] == 0) {
                              1 } else 2}

Database$Score
#[1] 0 0 0 1 2 2
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks this seems to have worked great. Would this still work when more data (more than 6 rows) or new data is added in 'MovementData' column? @akrun

Comment: @Aman Shergill : of course . Akrun used nrow(...) for the for-loop index,  which means it loops through every row until the last one.

Comment: perfect! Thanks for your help